# Running spring-boot's integration test cases using maven

Tags: java, maven-2, spring-boot

I am new to spring and maven. I want to execute certain test cases in `integration-test` phase of maven.
I tried doing that by applying `@IntegrationTest` annotation over those particular test cases but it is not working.

The maven command I am executing is: `mvn integration-test`

Comment: Try `mvn test` ... it's not an annotation used by Maven. It's there to let you control 'Spring' things such as what port the web server will listen on.

Comment: I had the same issue and was able to get it working by following http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing

Comment: thnx @chad its very helpfull :)